# AudioAnalyser with three.js

Tags: three.js

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/pulseball?path=cube_audio_analyser2.0.html%3A1%3A0

I am trying to create an audio analyser in Three.js (see link above) also the sound file is in the assets. I am getting an error three.js:41273 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
So i have put in sound.resume() in the play function (see code) but i the error is still there i can click on the play and pause buttons and the track is played but i don't think the audio analyser is working. I have looked at the docs and some examples from Three.js and the web audio api copied the code from these sources but there is no reaction from the musical data to animate the cube. Could someone please help as I am sure what to do next.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of CORS restriction, it's not possible to load the audio file from glitch. I've slightly updated your code and use now an audio file from the official three.js repository. Check out how the frequency data are logged in the browser console.

https://orchid-iodized-action.glitch.me

Comment: Thanks for the help i will have a look at the link you sent me